# Join values within multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I got the below object data which I need to join together, how can I achieve the output below provided that "foo" and "bar" would always have the same child elements.

```
{
  "foo": {
    "aaa": 1,
    "bbb": 2,
    "ccc": 3,
  },
  "bar:" {
    "aaa": "One",
    "bbb": "Two",
    "ccc": "Three",
  }
}
```

Expected output to be

```
<li>1 One</li>
<li>2 Two</li>
<li>3 Three</li>
```

Comment: What do you mean by you need to match the first xxx character? So if `bar` has `aaa` and also `aaa_foobar`, do you expect it to be merged with `foo`'s `aaa` key?

Comment: @Terry Sorry just rephrased my question.

Comment: Iterate though the keys in one of the objects and then use that to perform a look up in both objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var foobar = {
  "foo": {
    "aaa": 1,
    "bbb": 2,
    "ccc": 3
  },
  "bar": {
    "aaa": "One",
    "bbb": "Two",
    "ccc": "Three"
  }
};

let mappedArray = Object.keys(foobar.bar).map(xxx=> "<li>" + foobar.foo[xxx] + " " + foobar.bar[xxx] + "</li>");
console.log(mappedArray.join("\n"));
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a quite complex object manipulation expression. Assuming that you store your object in an `o` variable, this expression calling `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.map` couple of times will transform your object to an array of glued corresponding property values:

```js
const entries = Object.keys(o[Object.keys(o)[0]]).map(property => Object.keys(o).map(p => o[p][property]).join(' '));
```